# how to solve client connector error in python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, python-module

I have the code below

and I'm writing a bot for discord

but I get error

"`Exception has occurred: ClientConnectorError                                                Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [The specified network name is no longer available]`"

in the last line

code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def ready1():
  print('we have logged in')

  
@client.event

async def hello(message):
  if message.author==client.user:
    return
  if message.content.contains('hello'):
    await message.channel.send('hello')

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Have you re-generated the token? Are you familiar with the right names of `client.event`?

Comment: Try re-generating the token and put it into your code

Answer (score 0):

I just re-generate the token and it worked